# php preg_replace with strings containing |, [, ] signs

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have problem with this "simple" code:

```
$img_oryg = '<igm class="aligncenter" src="(oryginal img source)" alt="some text | some text">';
$replace_with = '<div class="ivcs_holder"><igm class="aligncenter" src="(oryginal img source)" alt="some text | some text" /></div>';
$content =  preg_replace("#$img_oryg#s", $replace_with , $contetn );
echo $content;
```

This is ofcourse a sample code, and everything is coded inside a loop, which overlap each image with divs, and also doeas some other stuff.
Problem is in | that can be added to alt-tag of image. If it is present, then code behave strangely and result is not correct.

Anybody does know how to deal with strings like that?

Comment: For the umptillionth+1 time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454   Do not use regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: Ok, now I know, that I should not use regexes to parse HTML - so what should I use to get same result?[?

Comment: @MarcB strangely enough, some XML/HTML parsers ARE WRITTEN using regexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be ok as long as you run [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on your regex pattern. the `|` character has a special meaning in regex, so this is why it would cause problems.

Comment: Or use str_replace to have same result as someone mentioned in comments :)
Oh, and Marc B's reply was rally helpful, couse now I will remember till death ;)